# Car physics Braking and Accelerating

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, everyday-life, inertia

Why does a car nose up when accelerating and nose down when braking. and when i try to move in reverse with the handbrake on the car rear move up ?[image]

Comment: Your picture shows the answer: the car's centre of mass is above the wheel axles. Hence there is a momentum that causes the car to rock

Comment: @hdhondt - I think the same thing would occur if the COM was co-planar with the wheel axles because the unbalanced force being applied is between the tire and the road, i.e., not at the height of the wheel axles.

Comment: @honeste_vivere You're right, of course.

Comment: The increased normal force on the front wheels when braking makes the front wheel brakes more significant than rear wheel brakes. The same effect for the back wheels makes rear wheel drive able to accelerate slightly faster than front wheel drive.

Comment: Does the car stays on ground due to torque from gravity (assuming the rear tyres don't touch the ground)?

Answer (score 4):

This results from [torque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque), $\boldsymbol{\tau} = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F}$.  In the braking case, the torque is out of the screen because the moment arm, $\mathbf{r}$, is generally downward and the force (i.e., between tire and road), $\mathbf{F}$, is generally directed toward the back of the car (e.g., see example diagram below).  In the acceleration case, the force is directed toward the front of the car and $\mathbf{r}$ is the same.
[image: force diagram examples]

The direction of torque defines the axis about which the object experiencing the torque will rotate (in a right-handed sense).  So in the braking(accelerating) case, the car will want to rotate in a counterclockwise(clockwise) sense.

Comment: i guess that car's braking system is designed to, as you brake harder, brake more on the front wheels than the rear 2- the brakes begin to drag and slow the wheels, but the rest of the vehicle is trying to stay in motion this is called (inertia) newton first law .the result of this is that some of the weight of the car transfers from the back wheels to the front wheels.and for the rear the chassis is trying to stay in the same place. the rear wheels are driving the car forward. i dont Know if this true or not

Comment: @A.trudeau - It's not about the front or rear brakes applying more or less force than the other.  It's about an unbalanced force being applied at a point that is not the center of mass.  The end result will be a torque.

Comment: the majority of the braking force comes from the front wheels, due to this weight transfer.

Comment: @A.trudeau - The car is made of incompressible materials, so how do you get a "weight transfer"?  The center of mass would not move very far relative to the length of the car during braking.  If it did, you would have a bad design as it would be vulnerable to rolling.

Comment: Oh, I see to what you are referring from your figure.  The center of mass (COM) does not move, its a relative change in the normal force between the front and back tires due to the slight rotation of the car about the COM.  However, this is misleading as mass does not actually move toward the front of the car.  The only thing changing is the angle between the normal to the ground and the plane through the COM and both axels.

Answer (score 0):

A car's tail typically rises when attempting to reverse with the handbrake (parking brake) still applied is down to the design of the rear suspension. Cars with a handbrake that acts on the front wheels, such as the Citroen BX, does not display this trait owing to the differing designs of typical front suspension/steering systems when compared to the rear. I will find & post some diagrams to illustrate.

Comment: No, the car will tilt forward so long as its center of mass is not co-planar with the ground (i.e., where the unbalanced forces are applied).  If the effect is less noticeable due to better suspension, that does not change the result (i.e., the torque will be in the same direction even if one applies only the rear brake).

Comment: @honeste_vivere there is no acceleration in the case that this answer addresses

Comment: @harold - How can there be no acceleration when applying the hand brake in a moving car?

Comment: @honeste_vivere because it isn't moving, it's stationary. The situation is, you apply the handbrake, then try to drive in reverse.

Comment: @harold - Then this should not have been posted as an answer because it is not related to the question which explicitly asks about acceleration.

Comment: @honeste_vivere the question also asked about this case, at least that is what "*try* to move in reverse" means to me

Comment: @harold - Ah I see to what you are referring.  The answer is still torque, though it would be between different things, similar to why the front end of an 18 wheeler twists sideways when initially accelerating with a large load.  In this case, the torque is internal but still requires friction with the road.

Comment: i guess that car's braking system is designed to, as you brake harder, brake more on the front wheels than the rear 2- the brakes begin to drag and slow the wheels, but the rest of the vehicle is trying to stay in motion this is called (inertia) newton first law .the result of this is that some of the weight of the car transfers from the back wheels to the front wheels.and for the rear the chassis is trying to stay in the same place. the rear wheels are driving the car forward. i dont Know if this true or not